# SQL Server secondary replica snapshot with Basic Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, snapshot, standard-edition

I have the following scenario:

I created an HA group of two nodes in SQL Server 2016 Standard (which is limited to two nodes, one database per group and a non readable secondary replica).
I tried to take a snapshot of the secondary non-readable replica, but it's didn't work and I can do that only on primary replica.

On failover snapshot replication (local publication) is moving automatically on primary replica.

From what [I read](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msftpietervanhove/2017/03/14/top-5-questions-about-basic-availability-groups/) it's possible to have a snapshot on secondary non-readable replica.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what is blocking you from doing this?

Comment: `but it's didn't work` - what error do you get ? Snapshot should just work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link refers to taking a [Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) of the secondary database, which was possible in Database Mirroring.

Remember there are lots of unrelated things that use the word "snapshot" in SQL Server:

> Database snapshots are unrelated to snapshot backups, snapshot
>   isolation of transactions, or snapshot replication.

It's not possible to use a Snapshot Replication with a secondary database:

> In an availability group a secondary database cannot be a publisher.
>   Republishing is only supported when transactional replication is
>   combined with Always On availability groups.

[Replication, change tracking, & change data capture - Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-2017)